# Excel 2007 VBA will not change Chart name

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have the following code

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim Graph As Chart
    Set Graph = AddGraph()
    Graph.name = "XXXX"
End Sub

Function AddGraph() As Chart
    Dim Graph As Chart
    '
    '
    '
    Graph.name = "XXXX"
    Set AddGraph = Graph
End Function
```

(Note that it is VBE that lowercases "name".)

In AddGraph, Graph is created with `Name="ChartXX"`. The assignment statement does NOT change the name.

In Foo, when the name assignment statement is executed, control is kicked all the way up to the top of the calling stack. (Other manipulations of Graph cause no problems.)

So I have two questions:

**1**) Why doesn't the name-change work in AddGraph? and

**2**) Why is the name-change later crashing in Foo?

Comment: `(Note that it is VBE that lowercases "name".) ` Have you defined a variable `name` somewhere? Some thing like `Dim name as String`

Comment: No. If you record a macro that changes the chart name, "name" is lower case.

Comment: No it doesn't :) It will only do that if you have declared `Dim name as ..` somewhere. Try this. Close All Excel files. Then open a new excel file. Fill 2 rows with dummy data. Create a chart and now record a macro. Check now :)

Comment: I ran the experiment, and you are right: "Name" is capitalized. In my code I noticed another routine that has a variable dim'd as a Name object, and "name" in the Dim statement is also l.c. There is no global variable "name" or "Name" in my project. I found a routine different than the ones I had been looking at that had a calling parameter "name". I changed it and now all "name"s are "Name"s. But my original two questions/problems remain.

Answer (score 2):

You neglected to tell us how AddGraph() adds a chart, or what kind of chart. Head of Catering assumes you added a chart sheet, in which case Graph.Name is a valid property. However, if you've added the chart as an embedded chart, Graph.Name is meaningless. Instead you must set the name of Graph's parent, the ChartObject:

Graph.Parent.Name = "XXXX"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem stems from Graph not getting set correctly to the chart object you're creating.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Foo()
    Dim Graph As Chart
    Set Graph = AddGraph()
    Graph.Name = "MMMMMMM"
End Sub

Function AddGraph() As Chart
    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
        .Name = "XXXX"
    End With
    Set AddGraph = ActiveChart
End Function
```

Step through it and you'll see your chart get named "XXXX" in the function and renamed to "MMMMMM" once it returns to the sub.